# Should I use Ionic 2 native date picker with an input element?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, datepicker, ionic2

I am wondering how should I use the Ionic 2 native date picker ?

- Through an input of type date ? If yes, how do I prevent the default behavior to show the native component ?
- Or should I use a tappable label for instance ?

Comment: just use https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/ ? or your question is not clear enough?

Comment: This is an interesting post that I found and I'm using in my projects: https://blog.jarmemori.es/tech/2016/09/14/display_ionic_datetime_picker_programmatically.html

Comment: Thanks @FabioCampinho but I am talking about the native date picker. Your blog post is about using the Ionic datetime picker instead of the native one.

Comment: Thanks @Akis but I found a solution and added it to the edit of my post. I am waiting to be able to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
<ion-input type="datetime" placeholder="Choisir une date" formControlName="date" (click)="onDateClick($event)"></ion-input>
```

And showing the native date picker within the onDateClick() function.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16555430)

Comment: I am just referring to my own answer to my own question. Doesn't get your point.

Comment: If you found a solution, you should post that as an answer, not update it into the question.